# Is there a way to get file object from the form in template?

Tags: django, django-forms, easy-thumbnails

### views.py

```
def manage_photo(request, obj_id):
    form = MediaFileForm(instance=obj)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Some actions here
        # ...

    return render(request, 'manage_photo.html', {'form': form,})
```

I would like to display an **image thumbnail** next to its form field on the form page. For that purpose I use [easy-thubmnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) module. I would like to write something like this in template:

```
<img src="{{ form.image|thumbnail_url:'small' }}">
```

But I can't, because {{ form.image }} is not a `File` object, which `thumbnail_url` filter takes as an argument.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you initialized the form with an instance, you can access that instance: `form.instance.image`.

Answer (score -1):

It takes the form `form.field.value`

```
<img src="{{ form.image.value|thumbnail_url:'small' }}">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but `form.image.value` returns a string, not a `File` object.